# Why does `cd` have no effect if output is piped?

Tags: pipe, cd-command

I accidentally typed

```
cd /tmp | tail
```

which is of course not what I meant.  But to my surprise, I then did not change directory.  Why is this?  For comparison

```
cd /tmp > /tmp/foo
```

*does* result in a change of directory, so it's not the output redirection per sé.  What's going on here?

Comment: The pipe spawns a subshell that exits when tail exits. I would have expected only tail to be in the subshell, but I guess the cd is as well.

Comment: But `cd /tmp | pwd` exhibits the same behavior -- `pwd` shows an unchanged working directory.

Comment: Each part of the pipeline is a separate process (maybe except last command).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipes involve subshells, portions of which are not run in the parent shell and thus cannot affect the working directory of that parent shell process. This is how ZSH behaves:

```
% cd /tmp
% cd /var/tmp | tail
% pwd
/tmp
% echo foo | cd /var/tmp
(pwd now: /var/tmp)
% cd /tmp
% echo foo | cd /var/tmp | echo bar
bar
% pwd
/tmp
%
```

Note how the directory only changed when the `cd` was the last command in the pipeline; this was run in the parent shell proper and thus was able to change the working directory of that process.

A useful use of this feature usually involves an explicit subshell and commands run therein:

```
dowork | ( cd elsewhere && domorework ) | andyetmore
```

also be sure to error check the `cd` call instead of assuming it worked, unless you like `rsync` output sprayed all over `/`, or other such hypothetical messes...

Comment: I understand why `tail` would need to be in a subshell, but I don't understand by the `cd` must be in a subshell, for the pipe to work.

Comment: having the parent process also run at various random points throughout the pipeline and handling I/O and deadlocks correctly would be much more complicated than simply forking off N children with the I/O wired up correctly